# Сохранение и загрузка данных из LocalStorage Python

Tags: python, selenium, telegram, get, localstorage

Хотел автоматизировать авторизацию в Telegram при заходе через webdriver selenium
Но у Telegram данные хранятся в local storage вместо cookies
Кто-то может помочь написать код для авторизации?

Comment: Написать за вас? Тогда на фриланс

Comment: Мне нужны только 2 строчки, первая как сохранить данные для авторизации, и вторая как и прочесть, надеялся что смогу найти ответ тут

Comment: Для куки я используя такой код

    pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), open(f"{Login1}_cookies", "wb"))

Я думал может кто-то сможет дать подобный для Local Storage

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Оказалось намного проще. Если кому пригодится, можно создать папку для каждого аккаунта

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=D:\\Profile1")
chrome_options=chrome_options
```

После того, как вы зайдете 1 раз, в следующий раз данные будут загружаться автоматически по этому пути